# WPF ProgressBar Visibility with MVVM does not Work

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I Have a WPF window that displays a list of records between 2 dates. I Use for that : MVVM Light, Entity Framework and Stored Procedure.

when I run the command to display the list, I want to display a progress bar to indicate that the task is running. When the query is finished I want to hide the progress bar.
The problem is that the visibility of the progress bar does not work well. Below is my code:

```
//XAML 
.
.
.
.
<StatusBar Grid.Row="2">

        <StatusBarItem Width="300">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SBMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>

        <StatusBarItem Width="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Requête en cours..." Visibility="{Binding TaskInProgress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booltovisibility}}" />
            <ProgressBar 
                Visibility="{Binding TaskInProgress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booltovisibility}}" 
                Width="100" 
                Height="20" 
                IsIndeterminate="True"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Grid.Column="1"
                />
            </Grid>

        </StatusBarItem>

    </StatusBar>


 //ViewModel

 bool _taskinprogress = false;
  public bool TaskInProgress
    {
        get { return _taskinprogress; }
        set
        {
            _taskinprogress = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TaskInProgress");
        }
    }

  public RelayCommand DisplaySimulationsListCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_splist == null)
                _splist = new RelayCommand(DisplaySimulationsListCommandExecute);
            return _splist;
        }
    }




    private void DisplaySimulationsListCommandExecute()
    {
        SBMessage = "Exécution...";
        TaskInProgress = true;
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        DoItWithStoredProcedure();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        SBMessage = ListSimulations.Count().ToString() +  " Enregistrement(s) en : " + elapsedTime;
        CurrentDisplayedTab = 1;
        TaskInProgress = false;

        //SBMessage = "Prêt";
    }






    private void DoItWithStoredProcedure()
    {

        try
        {

            using (UnitOfWork cx = new UnitOfWork())
            {
                var ls = cx.GetSimulationsPeriode(VMPeriode.Debut, VMPeriode.Fin).AsReadOnly();
                ListSimulations = new ObservableCollection<Simulation>(ls);
                CVS = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListSimulations);
                RaisePropertyChanged("CVS");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<ExceptionMessageRefresh>(new ExceptionMessageRefresh(ex), "DoItWithStoredProcedure");
        }
    }

//Converter
  public class BoolToVisiblityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// The default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public BoolToVisiblityConverter() { }
        #endregion


        public bool Collapse { get; set; }

        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool bValue = (bool)value;
            if (bValue)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            else
            {
                if (Collapse)
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                else
                    return Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;

            if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's most likely because you are performing a long operation on your main thread.  What does `DoItWithStoredProcedure` do?  Does it take a significant amount of time to execute?  If so, you will want to move that operation to a background thread.

Comment: the task takes about 1 sec for about 19000 Records. it performs a select query during a period from a sql server 2012 table that is indexed on date

Comment: Is it hitting the converter's Convert method at all?

Comment: Do what mittmemo said. while the records are being retrieved, the UI is frozen.  You could also checkout async commands [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx). You want to await the DoItWithStoredProcedure() so that the UI can update while the SP is running.

Comment: @HabibGherairi I edited my answer. Reading and understanding it should be much more intuitive and trivial than the other answer. I advise to steer clear of following the same pattern shown in Anjum's answer in future projects/tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is how they did it in the old days (pre-.NET Framework 4), when children would have to walk uphill to/from school.  Here is a much more readable solution that doesn't require an asinine amount of code (thanks .NET Framework 4/4.5).

```
private void DoItWithStoredProcedure()
{
    //Do your normal SP stuff here
    //Instead, I mocked a synchronous method 
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}

private void DisplaySimulationsListCommandExecute()
{
    //Do stuff 
    Console.WriteLine("Started");
    TaskInProgress = true;
    Task.Run(() => DoItWithStoredProcedure())
        .ContinueWith( task => { TaskInProgress = false; });
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    //Do the rest of your stuff
}
```

Output:

```
Started   //Showed the ProgressBar animation 
Finished  //Task.Run was hit
Completed //ProgressBar became collapsed after ContinueWith is hit
```

Proof:

[image: Working example]

As you can see, with your own eyes, this widely accepted method of using `Task.Run` and `ContinueWith` is a 1-line solution and can be read and understood very easily.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but problem with your code is TaskInProgress will always be false, as DoItWithStoredProcedure() will be executed asyncrhonously, so after your task statement control continues to TaskInProgress = false; . We can shift TaskInProgress = false; to DoItWithStoredProcedure() too, but as a design choice I went with event  handling pattern as it is more intuitive.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan revise my edited answer and please comment if you decide not to change your vote.  Same thing goes for downvoter who didn't comment.

Comment: @NetScape Sorry for the late. I tried your Code and it worded perfectly and it is more elegant. Thanks.

Comment: @NETscape Keep editing your incomplete / wrong answers. This makes downvoting feature useless. You posted a reckless answer without seeing whether it will work or not. I commented, then you changed it again. Everybody on this site will keep doing this with their answers.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I created an answer that I typed by phone and couldn't test. I edited it after I tested it. Are you honestly mad because your answer is not the best answer? Of course I'm going to correct my answer if it's wrong.

Comment: @NETscape  All users of SO will keep changing their wrong answers, then there won't be any wrong answer and there wont be any downvotes. See I didn't change my answer once question-owner checked it and after your comments. I check my answers before posting. Your first answer was outright wrong. Who is mad now ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I changed it because I knew there was clearly a better solution possible and I have the right and obligation to post the better answer.  I'm not going to post 2 answers when I had the intention to post one answer using Task. Calm down, it's okay, your answer would have been good about 6 years ago. Not so much today.

Comment: @NETscape You knew but you posted wrong solution, then corrected it after seeing an objection. You could have posted a new answer. Imagine what will happen if everyone starts changing their downvoted answers ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Well if their changed answer is better than the accepted answer and the original answer, who cares? We're here to provide good answers, not to show other how not to do it. Delete your answer if you're going to complain. Funny you didn't respond to my comment until the accepted answer changed.

Comment: @NETscape I was buisy with my work. Downvoting feature is here for a purpose. People like you spoil it.

Answer (score 1):

[@Habib Gherairi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071360/habib-gherairi), 
To avoid blocking the UI, you may need to add 'IsAsync=True' to your binding:

```
<ProgressBar Visibility="{Binding TaskInProgress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booltovisibility}, IsAsync=True}" IsIndeterminate="True" /
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx

> Use the IsAsync property when the get accessor of your binding source property might take a long time. One example is an image property with a get accessor that downloads from the Web. Setting IsAsync to true avoids blocking the UI while the download occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do asynchronous processing, as all UI levels changes will be available once complete function finished processing. In normal cases, processing takes negligible time so this scenario is not noticeable.

Suggested changes :

```
// suggested changes start //
            delegate void LongTaskDelegate();
            private void DoItWithStoredProcedureAsync()
            {
                LongTaskDelegate del = new LongTaskDelegate(DoItWithStoredProcedure);
                AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(LongTaskFinishedCallback);
                IAsyncResult result = del.BeginInvoke(callback, null);
            }
            private void LongTaskFinishedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
            {
                TaskInProgress = false;
                ... some extra work
            }
// suggested changes end //    
            private void DisplaySimulationsListCommandExecute()
            {
                ...

                TaskInProgress = true;                    

                // call our new method declared above
                DoItWithStoredProcedureAsync();                     
            }
```

If we use async / await pattern then there is no event like notification and we have to pollute our DoItWithStoredProcedure() with TaskInProgress = false; This can be done but not good practice. Our current pattern uses event like notification and notifies us of our long running task completion.

Comment: Check your convertor, why you are using collapse ? I cant see it getting set somewhere. Simple bool bValue = (bool)value;
            if (bValue)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            else                           
                return Visibility.Hidden;
            should be enough. Then in your progressbar binding, UpdateSourceTrigger is not needed as Mode is OneWay.

Comment: Also check your implementation of RaisePropertyChanged("TaskInProgress"); Replace DoItWithStoredProcedure(); in your code with for(long i=1;i<999999999;++i); to simulate a long running task and check.

Comment: For Collapse Property, I Edit my Code as follows <conv:BoolToVisiblityConverter  x:Key="booltovisibility" Collapse="False"/> and still does not work. For RaisePropertyChanged it is included in MVVMLight